# CONCAT in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

it does not runing,please show me where I have a mistake?

```
SELECT CONCAT(FIRST_NAME,',',LAST_NAME) as full_name FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

[image]

Comment: Try using the SQL operator `||`...

Comment: Did you check the documentation to see how many is a valid number of arguments?

Comment: BTW: Add error Messages as text not as image

Comment: For future reference, StackOverflow is a massive repository of previously answered questions. A search on `[oracle] concat ora-00909` would quickly have given you a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ANSI SQL's `||` instead to concat:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME || ',' || LAST_NAME as full_name FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

(`CONCAT()` function takes two arguments only.)

Comment: I know that but  want test with CONCAT functions

Comment: Why? `||` is portable and flexible.

Answer (score 4):

Concat only expects two Parameter, so you have to use nested concats:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME,','), LAST_NAME) as full_name FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

For more informations see the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm)

Answer (score 3):

**concat** takes 2 arguments. Try using it twice, like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME,','), LAST_NAME) as full_name FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Comment: thank you a lot ;)

Answer (score 2):

concat(String, String) is only use 2 parameters.
If you want use ','

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME||','||LAST_NAME as full_name FROM EMPLOYEES
```